# How to implement serializing for nested objects

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Had implemented a basic authentication system using `function based views` in django.

Trying to upgrade it to `class based views`.

Creating a `UserProfile` by inheriting from a django `User` model.

Need to serialize `UserProfile` and return to client side

**`User` model :**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

**`UserProfile` model :**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

**`UserSerializer`**:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
        read_only_fields = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'date_joined',)

        def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
            user = super(UserSerializer, self).restore_object(attrs, instance)
            user.set_password(attrs['password'])
            return user
```

**`UserProfileSerializer`:**

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('id','user','profile_picture',)
```

**views.py**:

```
class AuthView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        login(request, request.user)
        content={ 'user':UserProfileSerializer(request.user).data,'token':csrf.get_token(request)}
        return Response(content)
```

`UserProfileSerializer(request.user).data` in views.py is not working.
but instead if i use:
 `UserSerializer(request.user).data`, it gives me result(as expected) :

`{'first_name': '', 'username': 'admin', 'email': 'a@a.com', 'last_name': '', 'password': 'pbkdf2_'}`

But i also want additional attributes to the user also serialized like `profile_picture`, hence something like

`UserProfileSerializer(request.user).data`

should work for me.

**Questions**:

1. Is it possible to serialize a model containing `FileField` ?
2. How to serialize a nested object and return its data ?

Kinda beginner here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible to serialize a FileField. The problem is that your profile serializer needs a UserProfile model and not a User model. Try this:

`content={ 'user':UserProfileSerializer(request.user.user_profile).data,'token':csrf.get_token(request)}`

Comment: But `request.user.user_profile` doesnt exist. ryt? then how will it work  ?

Comment: ok so i made a `UserProfile` model and passed it into serializer and it worked......, but isnt this supposed to do it automatically, i mean something like:
i should pass the `user` model into the `UserProfileSerializer` and it should find the the corresponding user, assign it itself and return the serialized UserProfile model ........

Comment: It would work if you would do this in the opposite way. Return a User serializer that would include the user profile serializer too.

Please check the nested serializers documentation:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Comment: But that would mean in `User` model, there should be an added field,.... ryt ?...... Bcoz....... according to what i know......... in `fields` of serializers, only the attributes in the model can be added.

Comment: You can do the same thing in the User serializer that you did in the UserProfile serializer:

`class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):`
`    user_profile = UserProfileSerializer()`

Please read about reverse relations in django to understand how this work:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

As you can see in the example you can do things like:
`p1.restaurant`
 even if you don't have a foreign key to Restaurant.